# My "/" requestMapping sent me a WhiteLabel "/" error

Tags: java, spring, web, request-mapping

I want to simply map my home page with a Spring Controller like this :

```
package com.douineau.testspringboot.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping
//  @ResponseBody
    public String home() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

I also have `index.html` in `src/main/webapp` folder.
But the application does not recognize the mapping, whereas if comment this all, the app recognizes that it is my home page.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change **@Controller** to **@RestController.**
Your code should be like this.

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String home() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

or

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class HomeController {

 @GetMapping("")
  public String home() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mention you placed the index.html in your `src/main/webapp` but as I remember spring boot default configuration, it should be under `src/main/resources/templates` if it should be handled through your @Controller.

Everything in webapp is exposed "as-is" for eg. assets